# Port binding in powershell inside docker container

Tags: powershell, iis, docker-for-windows

I have a website hosted inside IIS docker container and it's listening at 443. I'm trying to bind one more port - 10000 with New-WebBinding. However, it's not working. The website is still accessible at 443 but fails at 10000. My new binding command looks like :

```
New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IPAddress "*" -Port 10000 -Protocol "https"
```

And Get-WebSites confirms that the port is bound to default web site.

Inside docker-compose file, I have port forwarding set up for both ports, and the request to 10000 is not even reaching to container(Because I don't see any entry for port 10000 in IIS log.). I also set-up inbound rule for port 10000. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: did you set a certificate for that 10000 port binding? to set certificate you could use this PowerShell script: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module WebAdministration
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd IIS:\SslBindings
PS IIS:\SslBindings> get-item cert:\LocalMachine\MY\7ABF581E134280162AFFFC81E62011787B3B19B5 | new-item 0.0.0.0!10000` . 7ABF581E134280162AFFFC81E62011787B3B19B5 is your certificate thumbprint. to get that you could run this command: `Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Comment: Yup I forgot certificate binding to port and figured that out yesterday. But thanks!

Comment: I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issues in the future. thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you set a certificate for that 10000 port binding? 
to set certificate you could use this PowerShell script:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module WebAdministration

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd IIS:\SslBindings PS IIS:\SslBindings> get-item cert:\LocalMachine\MY\7ABF581E134280162AFFFC81E62011787B3B19B5 | new-item 0.0.0.0!10000
```

7ABF581E134280162AFFFC81E62011787B3B19B5 is your certificate thumbprint.
 to get that you could run this command:

```
 Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard-code thumbprint, this is the code I use :

```
$cert = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$hostname*" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint  
$binding = Get-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -Protocol "https" -Port $port
$binding.AddSslCertificate($cert, "my")
```